# Link Git installed on my pc to Github

Tags: git, github, github-services

I have installed Git on my personal laptop. 
I want the project to be available on github, so that i can work remotely. Can i do it?

https://github.com/digantopaul/documents

Comment: Git is always local (unless you first remote into another machine).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

How to Work with Code

The code examples presented in this example are available from GitHub at https://
github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky.

The commit history in this repository was carefully created to match the order in which
concepts are presented. The recommended way to work with the code is to
check out the commits starting from the oldest, then move forward through the commit
list as you make progress.
You can also download each commit as a ZIP or TAR file.

If you decide to use Git to work with the source code, then you need to install the Git
client, (which you already did so skip this) which you can download from http://git-scm.com. The following command
downloads this example code using Git:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky.git
```

The git clone command installs the source code from GitHub into a flasky folder that
is created in the current directory. This folder does not contain just source code; a copy
of the Git repository with the entire history of changes made to the application is also
included.
In the first chapter you will be asked to check out the initial release of the application,
and then, at the proper places you will be instructed to move forward in the history.
The Git command that lets you move through the change history is git checkout. Here
is an example:

```
$ git checkout 1a
```

The 1a referenced in the command is a tag, a named point in the history of the project.
This repository is tagged according to the chapters of the book, so the 1a tag used in
the example sets the application files to the initial version used in Chapter 1. Most
chapters have more than one tag associated with them, so, for example, tags 5a, 5b, and
so on are incremental versions presented in Chapter 5.
In addition to checking out the source files for a version of the application, you may
need to perform some setup. For example, in some cases you will need to install addi‐
tional Python packages or apply updates to the database. You will be told when these
are necessary.
You will normally not modify the source files of the application, but if you do, then Git
will not let you check out a different revision, as that would cause your local changes to
be lost. Before you can check out a different revision, you will need to revert the files to
their original state. The easiest way to do this is with the git reset command:

```
$ git reset --hard
```

This command will destroy your local changes, so you should save anything you don’t
want to lose before you use this command.
From time to time, you may want to refresh your local repository from the one on
GitHub, where bug fixes and improvements may have been applied. The commands
that achieve this are:

```
$ git fetch --all
$ git fetch --tags
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

The git fetch commands are used to update the commit history and the tags in your
local repository from the remote one on GitHub, but none of this affects the actual
source files, which are updated with the git reset command that follows. Once again,
be aware that any time git reset is used you will lose any local changes you have made.
Another useful operation is to view all the differences between two versions of the
application. This can be very useful to understand a change in detail. From the command

line, the git diff command can do this. For example, to see the difference between
revisions 2a and 2b, use:

```
$ git diff 2a 2b
```

The differences are shown as a patch, which is not a very intuitive format to review
changes if you are not used to working with patch files. You may find that the graphical
comparisons shown by GitHub are much easier to read. For example, the differences
between revisions 2a and 2b can be viewed on GitHub at https://github.com/miguelgrin
berg/flasky/compare/2a...2b